# How do i read an incoming JSON from JavaScript inside a servlet in doPost()?

Tags: javascript, java, json, servlets

I'm trying to send some JSON information from a JavaScript client through XMLHttpRequest (Ajax) to a servlet in java, but i do not know the proper way of getting and decoding the data. I've seen many examples on the net, but no one seems to work. I just want to know wich method should i use like request.getParameter() and what kind of objects like JSONParser do i need. Every code or example i tried to use doesn't work, returns null in the parameters, or throws java.lang.NullPointerExceltion. The Post request arrives to the servlet because i monitorize the response, but i can't manage to acces the data. I'll post my codes. Many thanks to whoever can help me.

HTML (index.html):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>AJAX JSON Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxjsonfunctions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="PuMa" placeholder="Name..."/>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age" value="28" placeholder="Age..."/>
        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="Colombia" placeholder="Country..."/>
        <input type="button" id="sendjsonpost" name="sendjsonpost" value="Send JSON POST" />
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript, Ajax (ajaxjsonfunctions.js):

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var sendjsonpost = document.getElementById("sendjsonpost");

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    sendjsonpost.onclick = function()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("country").value;

        if (name == "" || age == "" || country == "")
            alert("Debe ingresar todos los datos.");
        else
            enviarDatosPost(name, age, country);
    }

    function enviarDatosPost(name, age, country)
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = prepararRespuestaPost;
        xhr.open("POST", "MessagesJSON", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        var datosJSON = crearDatosJSON(name, age, country);
        alert(JSON.stringify(datosJSON));
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(datosJSON));
    }

    function crearDatosJSON(name, age, country)
    {
        var datosJSON = {name : name, age : age, country : country};
        return datosJSON;
    }

    function prepararRespuestaPost()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (xhr.status == 200)
            {
                alert(xhr.responseText +" --- " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Servlet (MessagesJSON.java):

```
package com.puma.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.*;

@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = { "/MessagesJSON" })
public class MessagesJSON extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MessagesJSON()
    {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("name"));
            Iterator iterKey = jObj.keys(); //gets all the keys
            while(iterKey.hasNext())
            {
                String jsonKey = iterKey.next().toString();
                String jsonValue = jObj.getString(jsonKey);
                System.out.println(jsonKey  + " --> " + jsonValue  );
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the body of the request in the servlet, you need to call [`ServletRequest#getReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader--). In your case this would look like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
```

You can then pass this Reader into the constructor of `JSONTokener`:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(reader);
```

And finally you can parse this into a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(tokener);
```